What is the difference between shell scripting and bash scripting? (novice level answer)
What is the difference between shell scripting and bash scripting? I can't find any explanations at a reasonable level of familiarity to me.
I have read up on past stack overflow posts but they do not seem to directly answer my question.

Bash really is one shell of many, so it something like "Bash scripting is shell scripting, but shell scripting isn't necessarily Bash scripting". A more important distinction is sometimes to be made between Bash and POSIX shell scripting; Difference between sh and Bash talks about that.

@pjh That's not a good duplicate. "shell" doesn't mean "sh".

This is like asking "What's the difference between painting and painting with oil?"

A sub-answer to the closing duplicate explains shell vs sh vs bash.  But, @buggles, if you're really interested in scripting and all the features that are available (and the distinctions to be found), you'll do well to save a link to the main answer, and come back and reread as you learn more. Good luck.
